# Not able to start selendroid server

Tags: automated-testing, android, selendroid

I am new to Selendroid Testing and I went through the tutorial in the link below:

http://selendroid.io/setup.html

I run the command "java -jar selendroid.jar -app test-app.apk" like it is mentioned in the part called "Launching Selendroid" with the same resources used in tutorial but when I run it, I get this error output:

```
D:\test_workspace>java -jar selendroid.jar -app test-app.apk
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: ################# Selendroid #################
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: ################# Configuration in use #################
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidConfiguration@87aac27[
  port=4444
  timeoutEmulatorStart=300000
  supportedApps=[test-app.apk]
  verbose=false
  emulatorPort=5560
  deviceScreenshot=false
  selendroidServerPort=8080
  keystore=<null>
  keystorePassword=<null>
  keystoreAlias=<null>
  emulatorOptions=<null>
  keepEmulator=false
  registrationUrl=<null>
  proxy=<null>
  serverHost=<null>
  keepAdbAlive=false
  maxSession=5
  maxInstances=5
  registerCycle=0
  noWebViewApp=false
  noClearData=false
  sessionTimeoutSeconds=1800
  forceReinstall=false
  logLevel=ERROR
  deviceLog=true
  serverStartTimeout=20000
  printHelp=false
  serverStartRetries=5
  folder=<null>
  deleteTmpFiles=true
]
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher launchServer

INFO: Starting Selendroid standalone on port 4444
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Shell command output
-->

<--
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Shell command output
-->

<--
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/CERT.SF
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Shell command output
-->

<--
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.SF
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
SEVERE: Error executing command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remo
ve D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.SF
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit
value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecut
or.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
147)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp.deleteFileFro
mWithinApk(DefaultAndroidApp.java:112)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.deleteFileFr
omAppSilently(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:133)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(Se
lendroidServerBuilder.java:145)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:121)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.init
ApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:155)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<ini
t>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:94)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initialize
SelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:63)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(Sel
endroidStandaloneServer.java:52)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLa
uncher.java:65)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.j
ava:117)

Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.RSA
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
SEVERE: Error executing command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remo
ve D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.RSA
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit
value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecut
or.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
147)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp.deleteFileFro
mWithinApk(DefaultAndroidApp.java:112)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.deleteFileFr
omAppSilently(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:133)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(Se
lendroidServerBuilder.java:146)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:121)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.init
ApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:155)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<ini
t>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:94)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initialize
SelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:63)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(Sel
endroidStandaloneServer.java:52)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLa
uncher.java:65)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.j
ava:117)

Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.SF
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
SEVERE: Error executing command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remo
ve D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.SF
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit
value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecut
or.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
147)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp.deleteFileFro
mWithinApk(DefaultAndroidApp.java:112)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.deleteFileFr
omAppSilently(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:133)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(Se
lendroidServerBuilder.java:147)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:121)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.init
ApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:155)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<ini
t>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:94)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initialize
SelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:63)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(Sel
endroidStandaloneServer.java:52)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLa
uncher.java:65)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.j
ava:117)

Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remove
 D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.RSA
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
SEVERE: Error executing command: D:\android_sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe remo
ve D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk META-INF/NDKEYSTO.RSA
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit
value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecut
or.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
147)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp.deleteFileFro
mWithinApk(DefaultAndroidApp.java:112)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.deleteFileFr
omAppSilently(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:133)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(Se
lendroidServerBuilder.java:148)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:121)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.init
ApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:155)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<ini
t>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:94)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initialize
SelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:63)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(Sel
endroidStandaloneServer.java:52)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLa
uncher.java:65)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.j
ava:117)

Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
INFO: Executing shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\jarsigner.
exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar D:\test_workspace\resigned-tes
t-app.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\heba.ahmad\.android\debug.keysto
re D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk androiddebugkey
Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand exec
SEVERE: Error executing command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\jarsigne
r.exe -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar D:\test_workspace\resigned-t
est-app.apk -storepass android -keystore C:\Users\heba.ahmad\.android\debug.keys
tore D:\test_workspace\test-app.apk androiddebugkey
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\
jarsigner.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find
 the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13Com
mandLauncher.java:58)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:2
54)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecut
or.java:319)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
147)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:49)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServ
er(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:296)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(Se
lendroidServerBuilder.java:154)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:121)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.init
ApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:155)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<ini
t>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:94)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initialize
SelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:63)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(Sel
endroidStandaloneServer.java:52)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLa
uncher.java:65)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.j
ava:117)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more

Dec 25, 2016 8:11:53 PM io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher launchServer

SEVERE: Error building server: An error occurred while resigning the app 'test-a
pp.apk'.
Exception in thread "main" io.selendroid.server.common.exceptions.SessionNotCrea
tedException: An error occurred while resigning the app 'test-app.apk'.
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:124)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.init
ApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:155)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<ini
t>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:94)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initialize
SelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:63)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(Sel
endroidStandaloneServer.java:52)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.launchServer(SelendroidLa
uncher.java:65)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher.main(SelendroidLauncher.j
ava:117)
Caused by: io.selendroid.standalone.exceptions.ShellCommandException: Error exec
uting shell command: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigal
g MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar D:\test_workspace\resigned-test-app.apk
-storepass android -keystore C:\Users\heba.ahmad\.android\debug.keystore D:\test
_workspace\test-app.apk androiddebugkey
        at io.selendroid.standalone.io.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:56)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServ
er(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:296)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(Se
lendroidServerBuilder.java:154)
        at io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.addT
oAppsStore(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:121)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: io.selendroid.standalone.exceptions.ShellCommandException:
        ... 10 more

D:\test_workspace>


**Note that I searched a lot about it with no luck
so how can I fix this error?**
```

Comment: try re-starting your PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that I added Java JDK as environment variable like the answer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/3684096